# "Project from View" option doesn't appear?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I received this blender project elsewhere, so it could be something they have done, but I need project from view for the texture here, and it's just... not there, not sure what other information would help in this case. [image: image showing the "Unwrap" sub-menu without the option]

Comment: Your mouse has to be over a 3d viewport to have "project from view". It doesn't appear on the 2d image editor window.

Comment: oh my god... that makes so much sense yet i didn't consider it, thank you